# How to view console.log() output in Azure app service app

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I have a react app running fine on localhost:3000. When I deploy on Azure app service build and start up succeed but the error is that the app is not responding on 8080. Being able to view the output of console.log would really be a help to seeing whether the app is starting on the right port or not! I've configured app service logging but no log messages. I think both std.err and std.out should end up in the docker logs that I can view from VS Code. Is there something I could have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In azure webapp, the port only supports 80 and 443, usually we define `process.env.PORT || '3000'` in the code like this.

It is recommended to use [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) to make the deployment process more convenient.

**Test Sample code. ([offical sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world))**

I modify it for test.

[image]

**Deploy by git.**

[image]

**After deployed.**

[image]

**Setting `App Service logs`.**

[image]

**Check `Log stream`, you will find the content of `console.log`.**

[image]