# How to fix `Error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use` in azure app service?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have a nodejs/express app which I'm deploying to Azure Appservice on Linux platform.
Azure provides the port 8080 on which my app runs.
However, when I deploy it, it gives me an error

```
Error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8181
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

the main command with which I'm running the app is `env NODE_ENV=production node index.js`.

The port that the app uses is `8080`. But the error that's coming is for port `8181`. I've tried restarting the server and redeploying it many times over.

I followed this tutorial to deploy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux

I've deleted the whole appservice and its plan and redeployed it only to find the same error.

I ssh into the container and checked if `8181` is in use. But it isn't.

Here is how I am starting the application:

```
const port = 8080;
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the deploy log
[image]

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "test-express",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "nodemon index.js",
        "build:azure": "env NODE_ENV=production node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    }
}
```

In the official documentation that I've mentioned below, one of the scripts that starts the application is "build:azure".

Moreover, I added these lines to my code to see what environment variables are getting passed.

```
console.log("=============");
console.log(process.env.PORT, process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log("=============");
```

and the final result of the build process that I got was

```
...
7:00:08 pm test-express: [1/4] Resolving packages...
7:00:09 pm test-express: [2/4] Fetching packages...
7:00:30 pm test-express: info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:00:30 pm test-express: info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:00:30 pm test-express: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
7:00:45 pm test-express: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
7:00:45 pm test-express: Done in 37.21s.
7:00:45 pm test-express: Running 'yarn run build:azure'...
7:00:46 pm test-express: yarn run v1.22.10
7:00:46 pm test-express: $ env NODE_ENV=production node index.js
7:00:46 pm test-express: =============
7:00:46 pm test-express: 8181 production
7:00:46 pm test-express: =============
7:00:46 pm test-express: events.js:292
7:00:46 pm test-express:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
7:00:46 pm test-express:       ^
7:00:46 pm test-express: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
7:00:46 pm test-express: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8181
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Function.listen (/tmp/8d8e87f8a5dd6db/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/8d8e87f8a5dd6db/index.js:8:20)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
7:00:46 pm test-express: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
7:00:46 pm test-express:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
7:00:46 pm test-express:   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
7:00:46 pm test-express:   errno: -98,
7:00:46 pm test-express:   syscall: 'listen',
7:00:47 pm test-express:   address: '::',
7:00:47 pm test-express:   port: 8181
7:00:47 pm test-express: }
7:00:47 pm test-express: error Command failed with exit code 1.
7:00:49 pm test-express: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 14 -i /tmp/8d8e87f8a5dd6db -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
7:01:07 pm test-express: Deployment failed.
```

So yes, 8181 is getting passed.

**FIXED**:

Yes, I got it fixed by changing the script attribute `build:azure` to `start`. That was the only change I needed to make in `package.json` to get it to run.

Comment: can you post the screeshot? appservice does not expose port 8081

Comment: In the whole project, global search `8181` to see if there is relevant code, remember to use `process.env.PORT || 8080` instead.

Comment: @JasonPan I did a global search for `8181` and nothing came up. Yes I'm already using `process.env.PORT || 8080`

Comment: Try my way, tell me the results.

Comment: @JasonPan I logged the port that app service is passing and its actually passing 8181 as process.env.PORT. I manually deployed it to 8080 but its not getting deployed. It just errors out. Cant even see the logs through the portal.

Comment: @KartikeyaGokhale Pls follow my step show us Application Logs (all of them ), so we can help you.

Comment: @KartikeyaGokhale Pls also run `netstat -tunlp`, [and show us result img](https://i.imgur.com/zfOvfEe.png).

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: @JasonPan yes i fixed the issue. Was starting my app using "build:azure" as mentioned in the documentation. Had to change it to "start" and that did the trick. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**TroubleShoot :**

*Step 1 :*

[image]

*Step 2 :*

[image]

*Step 3 :*

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

Please modify the code in the code about listening.

Exp: ***const port = process.env.PORT || 8080***

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**Related Posts**

[1. Strapi on Azure does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355445/strapi-on-azure-does-not-run/62381339#62381339)

[2. How to view console.log() output in Azure app service app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671556/how-to-view-console-log-output-in-azure-app-service-app/64673643#64673643)

## If you change the port setting to process.env.PORT If it doesn't work.

Step 1: it is recommended to use git for continuous deployment, and the port setting is the same `process.env.PORT` According to the method in the post for reference. Then check whether the website is working properly.

Step 2: if the website fails to start normally, it is recommended to add start command. The first command to try is `npx serve -s`.

Step 3: if the command in step 2 does not work, use `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`.