# How to fix connect EADDRINUSE error in azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a node application running in an azure function that will read json files from the data lake. When I try to run the function I get the following error `connect EADDRINUSE 52.7.45.242:443at module.exports (C:\home\site\wwwroot\InitialLoadFunction\index.js:37:15)at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)`

I have restarted/stopped the function app and re-deployed the code but the error will not resolve. Anyone know how to clear the process that is using this address in azure?

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE means that the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use.

So, in your case, there must be running a server on specific port already.  Try [changing the port](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27508) or create a new function app and deploy.

Comment: Hey Sajeethran, I tried creating an creating an new function app but it did not work, as for changing the port, this issue is only happening for the deployed functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622874/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-in-azure-app-servic

Comment: Strangely the issue has resolved itself after a few hours, not sure why. thanks for the Help Sajeetharan.